# JTable showing only 1 row despite having more than 1 row count

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to load some data from a database (I use Oracle's SQL Developer) into a JTable in java. I put the data from the database in a Vector of Vector, this is my load method which I put in a class called DBJobs:

```
public Vector load() {
    try {
        Vector tableData = new Vector();
        Conn con = new Conn();
        con.openConn();
        con.statement = con.dbConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = con.statement.executeQuery("Select * from Jobs");

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            row.add(rs.getString("Job_ID"));
            row.add(rs.getString("Job_Title"));
            row.add(rs.getString("Parent_Job_ID_1"));
            row.add(rs.getString("Parent_Job_ID_2"));
            row.add(rs.getString("Description"));
            tableData.add(row);
        }

        con.closeConn();
        return tableData;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I tried populating them into a JTable which I've made with an editor in another class:

```
private void populateJobsTable() {
    Vector<String> tableHeader = new Vector<String>();
    tableHeader.add("Job ID");
    tableHeader.add("Job Name");
    tableHeader.add("Parent Job ID 1");
    tableHeader.add("Parent Job ID 2");
    tableHeader.add("Description");

    Vector tableData = dbJobs.load();
    tblJobs.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeader));
}
```

But all I can see is 1 row of data in the table. I've tried printing how many data the Vector has and how many rows the Table has and they're both returning 49, which is the amount of data I have in my database. So why is my table only showing 1 data?

Edit:
I think this is the code generated to make the JTable:

```
tblJobs = new javax.swing.JTable();
tblJobs.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    tblJobs.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Job Name"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    tblJobs.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(225, 16));
    jScrollPane5.setViewportView(tblJobs);
    if (tblJobs.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        tblJobs.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    }
```

Comment: How is the table displayed?  Have you tried using dummy data instead of loading it from the database?

Comment: I made the table in an editor, so I didn't have the setVisible(true) method in my code. Yes, I've tried using dummy data and it's still only showing 1 row.

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Grandevox, `I've tried using dummy data and it's still only showing 1 row.` - if you model has multiple rows of data and you set that model to the JTable and you add the table to a JScrollPane and add the scroll pane to the JFrame, then you will see all the rows in the table. If you don't then the problem is in your code. Maybe you have two models or two tables and the wrong table and/or model is added to the frame. The basic code you posted looks reasonable, but we don't know the context of how it is used which is why we need a `MCVE` with your hard coded data.

Comment: That is NOT an `MCVE`. We can't compile or test the code. We don't know the context of how the method is invoked and how the frame is created etc.

Comment: I actually put the 2 tables in different tabbed panes on the JFrame. Could it be where the problem is? And one other thing, I've tried populating it to the other table, and all the data showed up. What's wrong with this table? I made both tables in the same way

Comment: Okay I'll try looking for the code you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that is NOT a `MCVE`. How is that code complete? How can we compile and test that code? Did you not read my comment???

I would suggest you get rid of the IDE and learn how to create GUIs manually. What is the point of the IDE generating JTable with a custom TableModel. That code is completely useless since you then use create your own TableModel and use the setModel(...) method which will replace the model created by the IDE.

```
tblJobs.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(225, 16));
```

The above code looks suspicious. You should not be setting a preferred size on a Swing component. The size of the table looks like it will only display one row at a time.

It that is not the problem then I will have no more suggestion until a proper `MCVE` is posted. Every question should have a `MCVE` so we don't spend time guessing what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea where I could get the code for the MCVE that you were asking for. The reason I used an IDE to create my GUI is because I am not an expert at creating UIs (or in coding either) and I don't want to have to set the location for each object I put. I'll try creating GUIs manually if I don't have many objects on my frame. With that being said, I tried removing the code u said was suspicious and it worked! The table now displays all the data I have in my database! Thank you so much for your suggestion and I apologize if I confuse / frustrate everyone with my stupidity...

Comment: @Grandevox,  `The reason I used an IDE ` - the problem with the IDE is you learn the IDE and not Java/Swing. `and I don't want to have to set the location for each object I put.` - you should never set the location of an object. Swing was designed to be used with "layout managers". It is the layout managers job to set the size/location of a component based on the rules of each layout manager. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: okay I'll try to learn more about it. Thank you for your feedback!